# Promise and modify return value

Tags: javascript, promise

I need to modify existing code to support synchronous and asynchronous results. While I can easily handle `Task` and `await` in C#, even after reading a lot from MDN and other pages I just can't get my head around the JavaScript `Promise`.

The existing code looks like this:

```
function dispatchCall() {
    // ...

    try {
        let result = fn.apply(context, args);

        if (result !== undefined) {
            return { status: 0, result: result };
        }
        return { status: 0 };
    }
    catch (err) {
        if (typeof err === "object") {
            return { status: 400, errorMessage: err.name + ", " + err.message, stack: err.stack };
        }
        return { status: 400, errorMessage: err };
    }
}
```

`fn` is the function to be called. It is defined by the user of my API so I don't know what it will do. For now it will always return a value or throw an exception. That value will be wrapped in a message object that is passed back to the remote caller of `dispatchCall`.

Now `fn` needs to return a `Promise` because it is to be used in an asynchronous workflow where the result is not immediately available.

I need to test whether the `result` is a `Promise` (or "thenable") and act accordingly. In this case, when the result promise is resolved, I need to wrap the result value in the appropriate message object and pass that on as another promise to the caller of `dispatchCall`. I can then handle it there easily.

It's that "passing on and modifying the value" that I can't solve.

Here's how I would start things:

```
function dispatchCall() {
    // ...

    try {
        let result = fn.apply(context, args);

        // --------------------------------------------------
        if (result && typeof result.then === "function") {
            result.then(function (result) {
                // Like so?
                if (result !== undefined) {
                    return { status: 0, result: result };
                }
                return { status: 0 };
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                // Does this catch errors?
                if (typeof err === "object") {
                    return { status: 400, errorMessage: err.name + ", " + err.message, stack: err.stack };
                }
                return { status: 400, errorMessage: err };
            });
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                // What about this?
                // When should I call resolve and reject and with what arguments?
            });
            // Must return a Promise and not continue at this point!
        }
        // --------------------------------------------------

        if (result !== undefined) {
            return { status: 0, result: result };
        }
        return { status: 0 };
    }
    catch (err) {
        if (typeof err === "object") {
            return { status: 400, errorMessage: err.name + ", " + err.message, stack: err.stack };
        }
        return { status: 400, errorMessage: err };
    }
}
```

How should this be glued together?

After looking at the support tables, I decided to ditch Internet Explorer support and use ES6 Promises. No external library involved. In case some IE would execute this, it should continue to work with synchronous functions and is allowed to fail miserably with asynchronous code.

My target environments are browsers and Node.js.

Comment: Do you really need to return that object synchronously when `fn()` did not return a promise? It would be *much* easier if your function could always return a promise.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, because I don't want to use `Promise` unless necessary.

Comment: @ygoe need to change your way of thinking. If possibility of returning promise in any part of it then should return promise in all conditions and your call to `dispatchCall()` will always have a `then()` or `async/await`

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to create a promise with `new Promise` when you have a thenable.

You can just return `return result.then(......`, or if you want to be sure to return a Promise instance (not just whatever that `then().catch()` returns), then pass the result to: `Promise.resolve()`

```
    if (typeof result.then === "function") {
        return Promise.resolve(result).then(function (result) {
            if (result !== undefined) {
                return { status: 0, result: result };
            }
            return { status: 0 };
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            if (typeof err === "object") {
                return { status: 400, errorMessage: err.name + ", " + err.message, stack: err.stack };
            }
            return { status: 400, errorMessage: err };
        });
    }
```

If an error occurs in the `catch` callback then the returned promise will resolve as rejected. The caller could handle that with its own `catch` chained to it.

Comment: You would wrap only the `result` in the `Promise.resolve()` call, not the result of calling the method (and even chaining a `catch`) on the thenable.

Answer (score 2):

Because the result may be retrieved asynchronously, the consumer of `dispatchCall` *must* have logic to wait for the possibly-asynchronous data to come back. One option would be for `dispatchCall` to return a Promise that ultimately resolves to the `{ status, result }` object (or `{ status, error }` object) you're looking for:

```
if (typeof result.then === "function") {
  return result
    .then((resolveValue) => {
      return { status: 0, result: resolveValue };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return { status: 400, error };
    })
}
```

And in the consumer of `dispatchCall`, check if the returned value is a Promise - if it is, call `.then` on it:

```
const dispatchResult = dispatchCall();
if (typeof dispatchResult.then === 'function') {
  dispatchResult.then(({ status, result, error }) => {
    // do stuff with status, result, error here
    // if there was an error, result will be undefined
  });
} else {
  // do stuff with dispatchResult.status, .result, .errorMessage
}
```

You could also consider returning a Promise *regardless* of whether `result` is a Promise or not, so as to make the code easier to manage - for example, in the synchronous section:

```
return Promise.resolve({ status: 0, result: result });
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to return that object synchronously when `fn()` did not return a promise? It would be *much* easier if your function could always return a promise. You would simply `resolve` with the value, and regardless whether it was a plain value, thenable or promise, you get a promise back from it.

Then you'd chain your result/error handling logic to that, just once:

```
function dispatchCall() {
    // ...

    // return Promise.resolve(fn.apply(context, args))… - doesn't catch synchronous exceptions
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        resolve(fn.apply(context, args)); // promise constructor catches exceptions
    }).then(function (result) {
        // the promise was fulfilled
        if (result !== undefined) {
            return { status: 0, result: result };
        } else {
            return { status: 0 };
        }
    }, function (err) {
        // the promise was rejected
        if (typeof err === "object") {
            return { status: 400, errorMessage: err.name + ", " + err.message, stack: err.stack };
        } else {
            return { status: 400, errorMessage: err };
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, because I don't want to use `Promise` unless necessary. Also, very importantly, `fn` might also return nothing at all, in which case I must send a message with status 0 but no result. This is for void functions.

Comment: @ygoe If `fn` returns nothing at all, the object will have a `result` property an `undefined` value. JSON serialisation will strip that away completely. I doubt it's important to omit the property completely.

Comment: @ygoe What do you mean by "unless necessary"? Promises are cheap, and using them makes everything much simpler to handle. Is there an actual need for a synchronous result?

Comment: I've looked it up and there is no actual need for a synchronous result from `dispatchCall`. But as I said I'd like to keep up IE support for those scenarios that can be done. If the user of my library decides to add some 3rd party lib for promises and my lib could just reuse that, that's fine, but I don't want to introduce such a dependency unless necessary, i.e. the user wants async code.

Comment: @ygoe If that's the choice, then you should probably better ship two versions of your library, one that is synchronous and another that uses promises. Having two codebases (or maybe just build options) will be easier to deal with than mixing sync and async logic in the same code and having an optional dependency on promises.

Comment: Oh, and JSON serialisation may ignore the undefined value (just checked here in Firefox), but MessagePack serialisation (which I use) may not. So I need the separate code.